# obtener el nombre de todos los usuarios de mi firebase

Tags: android, firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiere obtener el nombre de todos los usuarios pero no logro entrar hasta el nodo, ya estuve investigando, por favor alguna sugerencia.

este es el código que utilizo para que me den una idea por favor.

Quiero obtenerlo para posteriormente guardarlo en una lista y poder manipularlo.

```
 database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    addU = database.getReference(bdreference.userRefence);
    addU.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            key= dataSnapshot.getKey();
            nombre=dataSnapshot.child(key).child("nombre").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i("nombre",nombre);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes obtener una lista con los nombres iterando sobre `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("usuarios")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    List<String> usuarios = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        usuarios.add(childSnapshot.child("nombre").getValue(String.class));

                    // usuarios ahora contiene los nombres de todos los usuarios.
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```