# Como listar los Post de todos los usuarios Android Firebase?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hasta ahora solo se muestran vacios los campos

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Usuarios/");

mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {


        //dismissing the progress dialog
        progressDialog.dismiss();


      
        //iterating through all the values in database

        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {



            String upload = postSnapshot.child("PostLinks ").getValue(String.class);


            subidas.add(0, upload);


        }

        adapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(0, (int) snapshot.getChildrenCount()); 

       if (subidas.size() != snapshot.getChildrenCount()) {
            seeNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }



});[![En la imagen estan los child][1]][1]
```

Comment: Te recomiendo usar firestore en ves de real time database. real time data base mayormente se usa para localizacion en tiempo real o otras cosas. Ya q es un poco mas rapido que firestore.

Comment: Entonces si Real Time Database es más rápido, porque me recomiendas Firestorage?

Comment: se basa en modelos de datos y es mas facil de usar, puedes hacer consultas.

Comment: Suena muy cool entonces.

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque tiene texto spam

Comment: @RuslanLópez te refieres al Lorem Ipsum ??

Comment: sí y a que ya tenía una respuesta en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/124397/obtener-el-nombre-de-todos-los-usuarios-de-mi-firebase?rq=1

Comment: Entonces repórtala como duplicada.